# Customize the route prefix pattern using Vue-Router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am trying to use Vue-Router to pattern URLs in my new project so they look just like URLs in an existing (non-Vue) application.  Existing application URLs look like this:

- `/#!page1`
- `/#!page2`

My Vue Router currently looks like this:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      redirect: '/page1'
    },
    {
      path: '/page1',
      component: Assessments
    },
    {
      path: '/page2',
      component: Assessments
    }
  ]
})
```

But, of course, this generates URLs that look like this:

- `/#/page1`
- `/#/page2`

How can I configure my router to mimic the `/#!route` pattern?

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `base` option:

> ### base
>
> - type: string
> - default: `"/"`
>
> The base URL of the app. For example, if the entire single page
>   application is served under `/app/`, then base should use the value
>   `"/app/"`.

https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/options.html#base

I have tried it with your case, it also works with `/#!`.

Comment: I can indeed get the browser to display the URL in the desired format in the location/search bar using `base` like this:
`{
  base: '/#!',
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      redirect: 'page1'
    },
    {
      path: 'page1',
      component: Page1
    },
    {
      path: 'page2',
      component: Page2
    }
  ]
}`
But if I then refresh the browser, the router does not load the proper page.  For instance,if I am on `/#!page2`  and I refresh, I go to `/#!/page1#!page2`.

Comment: Seems that this is an issue of vue router. But I don't know that there is another way to do this beside `base` option.

Comment: Works for me in my use case. Thanks @wxsm !

Answer (score 0):

For Vue 3 and Vue Router 4 The base option is now passed as the first argument to createWebHistory:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
    createRouter({
        history: createWebHistory('/base-directory/'),
        routes: [],
})
```

[Migrating from Vue 2 documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/migration/#Moved-the-base-option)